# Weird behavior with OO-Javascript and global variables

Tags: javascript, oop, global

I have a *global* array of objects like so

```
var data = {};
data.meta = [{..},{..},{..}];
```

Then I define a Javascript class like so:

```
var ui = {};
ui.Ruler = function(d) {
    this.d = d;
    this.o = null;
};

ui.Ruler.prototype.render = function () {
    console.log('render');
    return this.o;
};
```

I can access `data.meta` from the dev console and it shows me its contents. 
However,
when I initialize an instance of the class and pass it an object of `data.meta`,

```
var ruler = new ui.Ruler(data.meta[0]);
```

The console gives me an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined*

Furthermore, `data.meta` is `undefined` all of a sudden. How can this be? What am I doing wrong? I want `data.meta[0]` to be available inside the instantiated `ruler` object. If I do not run this line, `data.meta` is still defined. Can somebody explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: Don't use `var` to declare a global variable. To make a variable explicitly global, define it as `window.data = {}` and refer to it as `window.data`.

Comment: I seem to have trouble replicating the issue. Can you provide a fiddle that does?

Comment: Read the error message. `data` is defined, but it doesn't have a `meta` property. That means the error is likely not related to the code you have provided above (since the code above properly defines a `meta` property on `data`.) is `data` being overridden?

Comment: This is so weird. I cannot replicate it inside a jsFiddle. When I execute `var ruler = new ui.Ruler(data.meta);`, i.e. without choosing an object but passing the whole array, `data.meta` is still defined (outside the object). But: `ruler.d === undefined`. However, when I, after running this code, execute `var ruler2 = new ui.Ruler(data.meta[0])` directly in the console, it works, and `ruler2.d === {...}`.

Comment: OK, shame on me, I found it out - upon calling `var ruler = new Ruler ...`, `data.meta` had not been defined - it was populated by an async request and I forgot to wait for the answer to execute `var ruler...`. Embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

I seem everything is ok. 
I've tried to run it in FF and Chrome - ok.
Here is my fiddle  [testing link](http://jsfiddle.net/RANj8/)

```
var ruler = new ui.Ruler(data.meta[0]);
```

(I can't comment)